# how to set socks5 proxy in the terminal

Tags: command-line, ssh, syslinux

I am a beginner using linux, I would like to connecting the terminal to the local proxy socks made by my ssh (Dynamic Port Forwarding),

so is there a way to set up a proxy socks5 in the terminal?

or should use an additional module,

or have to go through another tool,

thank you for your attention

Answer (score 17):

I'm using [Proxychains](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng), an easy to use command line tool.
Usage:

```
sudo proxychains4 apt-get update
```

You can configure you proxy in the `/etc/proxychains.conf`

```
[ProxyList]

socks5  127.0.0.1 12345
```

Comment: 'sudo proxychains apt-get update' work for me

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Official use is:

```
ssh -D 8080 name@myserver.com


export http_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:8080"
export https_proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:8080"
```

no need to install anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http_proxy environmentvariable like this:
export http_proxy="socks5://localhost:9050"
Now the terminal will use that as proxy.
Here I'm using tor proxy, but should work for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Proxychains is very nice tool, but there are certain use cases that it does not support. What that worked for me was [graftcp](https://github.com/hmgle/graftcp) based on this [comment](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/issues/199#issuecomment-410145316).

The installation is easy:

```
git clone https://github.com/hmgle/graftcp.git
cd graftcp
make
```

Using it is even easier:

```
./local/graftcp-local &   # runs the tunnel in the background to localhost:1080
./graftcp curl ipecho.net/plain
```

as you observe from the last command, your IP address has been changed. You can run any command you like by just prefixing graftcp:

```
./graftcp go build
```